# Hplip prints everything as booklet

Tags: hp, compatibility

When setting up my HP deskjet 4630 I must have done something wrong and now every print is in booklet format (two sides for any face).

I have a 14.04 Ubuntu system.

Comment: Check Printers->Properties and see if you can find an incorrectly set option.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal window ans type:

`sudo apt-get installhplip-gui` .

A nice HP Utility will appear in the main menu. It's a graphical interface for hplip with many useful options, like printing booklet or 'normal' mode.